# Выровнять элементы <li> при малом разрешении

Tags: html, css

Есть такая структура разметки, thymeleaf который заполняет фронт данными из java.
такая проблема.

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{java}">
            <li class="first">Быстрый выбор:</li>
            <a4j:ajax event="click"
                {//логика ajax}
                <li><a4j:commandLink id="c242_link" value="1" actionListener="#{java}" />&#8202;,</li>
                <li><a4j:commandLink id="c1_link" value="2" actionListener="#{java}" />&#8202;,</li>
                <li><a4j:commandLink id="c209_link" value="3" actionListener="#{java}" />&#8202;,</li>
                <li><a4j:commandLink id="c32_link" value="4" actionListener="#{java}" />&#8202;,</li>
                <li><a4j:commandLink id="c251_link" value="5" actionListener="#{java}" /></li>
            </a4j:ajax>
        </h:panelGroup>
```

сначала данные выстраиваются в строку

```
Быстрый выбор: 1,2,3,4,5
```

когда разрешение уменьшаются строка трансформируется

```
Быстрый выбор: 1,2,3,
               4,5
```

а когда совсем маленькое разрешение позиция 5 почему то съезжает влево. мне нужно чтобы она оставалась по 1,4 на одной вертикали. как это сделать?

```
Быстрый выбор: 1,2,
               3,4,
5
```

Answer (score 0):

сделал может и не очень красиво но сработало

добавил `height: 50px` к css для `< li class="first" >`